Adding an image to a pdf using Rust and lopdf
Using Rust, I'm trying to add a png file into a PDF first page using the following code:
File: main.rs
mod merge_to_pdf;

const OUT_CHART: &str = "C:\\Projects\\pie_chart\\pie-chart.png";
const TAX_STATEMENT: &str = "C:\\Projects\\pie_chart\\tax_statement.pdf";
const MERGED_TAX_STATEMENT: &str = "C:\\Projects\\pie_chart\\tax_statement_merged.pdf";

fn main() {
    
    merge_to_pdf::merge_image_to_pdf(&OUT_CHART, &TAX_STATEMENT, &MERGED_TAX_STATEMENT).unwrap();
}

File: merge_to_pdf.rs
use image::{GenericImageView, DynamicImage};
use image::codecs::jpeg::JpegEncoder;
use lopdf::{Document, Object, Stream, dictionary};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Cursor, Read};


pub fn merge_image_to_pdf(image_path: &str, pdf_path: &str, pdf_output: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {


   // Load the PDF document
   let mut doc = Document::load(pdf_path)?;
   println!("PDF loaded successfully.");

   // Load the image
   let mut image_file = File::open(image_path)?;
   let mut image_data = Vec::new();
   image_file.read_to_end(&mut image_data)?;
   let image = image::load_from_memory(&image_data)?;
   let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
   println!("Image loaded successfully with dimensions: {}x{}", width, height);

   // Convert the image to JPEG format if it's not already
   let mut jpeg_data = Vec::new();
   {
       let mut cursor = Cursor::new(&mut jpeg_data);
       let mut encoder = JpegEncoder::new(&mut cursor);
       encoder.encode_image(&image)?;
   }
   println!("Image converted to JPEG format.");

   // Create an image XObject
   let image_xobject = Stream::new(
       dictionary! {
           "Type" => "XObject",
           "Subtype" => "Image",
           "Width" => width as i32,
           "Height" => height as i32,
           "ColorSpace" => "DeviceRGB",
           "BitsPerComponent" => 8,
           "Filter" => "DCTDecode",
           "Length" => jpeg_data.len() as i32,
       },
       jpeg_data,
   );

   // Add the image to the document
   let image_id = doc.add_object(image_xobject);
   println!("Image XObject added to the document with ID: {:?}", image_id);

   // Get the first page
   let page_id = *doc.get_pages().keys().next().ok_or("No pages found in PDF")?;
   println!("First page ID: {:?}", page_id);

   // Add the image to the page resources
   {
       let page = doc.get_object_mut((page_id, 0))?;
       if let Object::Dictionary(ref mut page_dict) = *page {
           // Ensure the Resources dictionary exists
           if !page_dict.has(b"Resources") {
               page_dict.set("Resources", dictionary! {});
           }

           let resources = page_dict.get_mut(b"Resources").unwrap();
           if let Object::Dictionary(ref mut resources_dict) = *resources {
               // Ensure the XObject dictionary exists
               if !resources_dict.has(b"XObject") {
                   resources_dict.set("XObject", dictionary! {});
               }

               let xobjects = resources_dict.get_mut(b"XObject").unwrap();
               if let Object::Dictionary(ref mut xobjects_dict) = *xobjects {
                   xobjects_dict.set("Im0", image_id);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   println!("Image added to the page resources.");

   // Add the image to the page content at a specific location
   let x_position = 100.0; // X position where the image will be placed
   let y_position = 100.0; // Y position where the image will be placed

    // Check the Image Coordinates and Transformation Matrix
    let content = format!(
        "q\n{} 0 0 {} {} {} cm\n/Im0 Do\nQ\n",
        width, height, x_position, y_position
    );
   println!("Content stream created: {}", content);

   let content_stream = Stream::new(
       dictionary! {
           "Length" => content.len() as i32,
       },
       content.into_bytes(),
   );

   let content_id = doc.add_object(content_stream);
   println!("Content stream added to the document with ID: {:?}", content_id);

   // Ensure the Content Stream is Correctly Added
   {
       let page = doc.get_object_mut((page_id, 0))?;
       if let Object::Dictionary(ref mut page_dict) = *page {
           // Update the Contents entry
           if let Ok(contents) = page_dict.get_mut(b"Contents") {
               match contents {
                   Object::Reference(content_ref) => {
                       let content_array = vec![Object::Reference(*content_ref), Object::Reference(content_id)];
                       *contents = Object::Array(content_array);
                   }
                   Object::Array(content_array) => {
                       content_array.push(Object::Reference(content_id));
                   }
                   _ => {
                       *contents = Object::Array(vec![Object::Reference(content_id)]);
                   }
               }
           } else {
               println!("Contents does not exist");
               page_dict.set("Contents", Object::Reference(content_id));
           }
       }
   }
   println!("Content stream appended to the page.");

   // Save the modified PDF to the output path
   doc.save(&pdf_output)?;

    Ok(())
}

The application runs without any issues.  And when I look at the output pdf using PDFExplorer, I see the image is in the PDF.


Note: The piechart shown above is what is I see when I click on the Img0 in PDFExplorer.  So its in the PDF resource, but the problem is that when viewing the actual PDF in Reader for example, the piechart doesn't show.
Using pdfcpu shows the image in the output pdf also.

I've added print!() to see the output and this is what I get:
PS C:\Projects\pie_chart> .\target\debug\pie_chart.exe
PDF loaded successfully.
Image loaded successfully with dimensions: 300x250
Image converted to JPEG format.
Image XObject added to the document with ID: (386, 0)
First page ID: 1
Image added to the page resources.
Content stream created: q
300 0 0 250 100 100 cm
/Im0 Do
Q

Content stream added to the document with ID: (387, 0)
Content stream appended to the page.

using the following library version:
lopdf = "0.33"
image = "0.25"

The image is a pie chart and should look like this sample pdf file.

Instead I'm just getting the following output with no visible pie chart around the red square to show where it should be (red square was added using Gimp).

What am I missing?
Full code is available in GitHub.

What is missing is that the second image has been attached to the wrong part of the whole file not a page, so is "unseen". But it has also been attached as same identity as the logo /Im0 so even if it was seen it would look like this.

Rather than this

So this is an answer but not a fix, as I don't use Rust to say exactly where it needs changing.
